# ViewPager destroyItem() [position 1] is not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager

First of all what i am trying to do is, a simple video program which contains 3 pages of ViewPager, and first page has list of videos, second has only one VideoView, and third one is another list view. Program works just fine but when i try to swipe between pages, video doesn't stop playing(App starts in page 1 by default which is videoview). I've tried adding onClickListener to start video, which solved the problem autostart as program starts. But still, it keeps playing when i change the page.

Here is page initiation part:

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view;
        switch (position) {
            case 0: {
                // Inflate a new layout from our resources
                view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_listed_videos,
                        container, false);
                // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
                container.addView(view);
                list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
                GetVideoPosts getVideoPosts = new GetVideoPosts();
                getVideoPosts.execute();
                updateList();
                list.setAdapter(new CustomList(getActivity(), mVideoUrls, mVideoTitles));
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject job1 = mVideoData.getJSONObject("data");
                            JSONArray jsonPosts = job1.getJSONArray("items");
                            JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(position);
                            JSONObject url = post.getJSONObject("player");
                            String title = url.getString("default");
                            title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VideoViewActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("url", title);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Return the View
                return view;
            }
            case 1: {
                ((ViewPager)container).setCurrentItem(1);
                view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_video_view,
                        container, false);
                container.addView(view);
                GetVideoPosts getVideoPosts = new GetVideoPosts();
                getVideoPosts.execute();
                updateList();
                final VideoView vv = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
                MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                        getActivity());
                mediacontroller.setAnchorView(vv);
                String videoUrl ="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4";
                Uri video = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
                vv.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
                vv.setVideoURI(video);
                // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager

                container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        showLoadingImageDialog();
                        vv.requestFocus();
                        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                vv.start();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                return view;
            }
            case 2:
                view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
                        container, false);
                // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
                container.addView(view);

                // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
                TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
                title.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

                // Return the View
                return view;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and the output:

```
12-20 3435-3435/SlidingTabsBasicFragment﹕ destroyItem() [position: 0]
12-20 3435-3435/SlidingTabsBasicFragment﹕ destroyItem() [position: 2]
12-20 3435-3435/SlidingTabsBasicFragment﹕ destroyItem() [position: 0]
12-20 3435-3435/SlidingTabsBasicFragment﹕ destroyItem() [position: 2]
```

I am skipping through position 1 but no destroyItem function log shown.

**Note:** Any other ideas for displaying the video will be appreciated. You can think of this app as Vine app, for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do here is to set `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);` so that your page destroys whenever your leaves that pages thus destroying your `VideoView` as well. Simple

Comment: can you be more specific? since im not calling any fragments by FragmentPager. so i can't add OnUserVisibiltyHint. Please take a time and check my code

Comment: still not destroying and i can hear the video playing sound while im scrolled to another page... thanks for answer tho.

Comment: so what i think that you need to have different implementation of `PagerAdapter` where you can utilize `setUserVisibiltyHint()` method to stop `VideoView`